# Can you give how does vs code "add configuration" works?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I recently wanted to add a node configuration for vs code. VS code has an add configuration link in run.
I liked to know how to add a configuration?

Comment: This link can help you https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_add-a-new-configuration

Answer (score 0):

You specify it in the debugger part of `package.json`

https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/contribution-points#contributes.debuggers